# How to create responsive layout with react-semantic-ui?

Tags: semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

How to create the layout as given below?

[image: Semantic ui layout example]

The layouts `A` and `B` in mobile must stack one after other.
In the bigger screen the layout `B` must be togglable. Whereas, `A` adjusts to full screen or half according to the visibility of `B`.

**My code sample**

```
<Grid.Row>
  <Grid.Column computer={16} largeScreen={10}>
    <A />
  </Grid.Column>
  {showB && (
      <Grid.Column computer={16} largeScreen={6}>
        <B />
      </Grid.Column>
  )} 
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to declare the column A width in a variable that would change depending on if column B is open or not. A solution for that is here https://codesandbox.io/s/8843zowzj9

As `semantic-ui` `Grid.Row` can have a width of 16 units, columns A would start with that width, and it would decrease if you show column B (by the width you desire) or increase once you hide it.

The `stackable columns={2}` attributes in the `Grid` tag makes this clever enough to also make them stack once the screen reaches a mobile resolution.

Comment: Thanks! Could you also help me out with transition. I tried here, https://codesandbox.io/s/936kl59n7o , but it doesn't looks seamless.